How to Handle Redirecting to the Next Page After Login in Django
I'm new to django and wanted to test out the login required mixins and the redirecting to the next_urls. The login works fine, but after login it goes to the index page instead of the page the user wanted to visit. For example, if this is the url
http://localhost:8000/post/login/?next=/post/1/

It redirects to this link after login
http://localhost:8000/post/

Here is a snippet of the
views.py
def loginUser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Login(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                next_url = request.GET.get('next', None)
                post_id = request.GET.get('post_id', None)
                print("Next URL:", next_url)
                print("Post ID:", post_id)
                if next_url:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)
                else:
                    return redirect('posts:posts-index')
    else:
        form = Login()
    return render(request, 'posts/login.html', {'form': form})

class Content(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'posts/post.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    login_url = 'login/'

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            post_id = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
            next_url = reverse('posts:posts-content', kwargs={'pk': post_id})
            return redirect(reverse('posts:loginUser') + '?next=' + next_url + '&post_id=' + str(post_id))
        return super().handle_no_permission()

    model = Post
```


urls.py
```
app_name = 'posts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', Index.as_view(), name='posts-index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', Content.as_view(), name='posts-content'),
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
    path('login/', loginUser, name='loginUser'),
    path('logout/', logoutUser, name='logoutUser'),
    path('profile/', profile, name='profile')
]
```

and my login.html
```
    {% extends 'posts/base.html' %}
    {% block title %}
       Sign Up
     {% endblock %}
     {% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'posts:loginUser' %}{% if next %}?next={{ next }}{% endif %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```


I tried printing the url_next value but i keep getting none.I also tried adding

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'posts:loginUser' %}" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}" />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```


Don't do anything in UI i.e.html template pages as the information is already there in URL :
in  loginUser
def loginUser(request):
    nextpage = request.GET.get("next", None)
    if nextpage:
        return redirect(nextpage)

that all you need to do.
also add this to the form if it doestnt work without it
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">

for more information refer documentation
